# How to assess effect of a treatment on different groups, if groups have an effect on the measured variable and each group only receives one treatment?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Let's say I want to assess the effect of a treatment (A or B) on a continuous variable measured on subjects.

The subjects I want to experiment on are organized into "groups". It has been previously demonstrated that the "group" a subject is a part of can have an effect on the continuous variable I want to measure. Also, each member from the same group has to receive the same treatment.

One thing I could do is calculate the average of each group, and test the averages of groups that received A vs the averages of the groups that received B (with t-test or non-parametric equivalent). However, this strikes me as "underpowered".

Is there any method that, perhaps by taking into account the variance in each group, might be more powerful?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you please clarify? For each group would you have pre and post treatment measurements? or only post treatment measurements?

Comment: I don't think it really makes a difference, but let's assume post treatment only. I suppose if pre treatment measures were available the difference pre and post treatment could be measured, which would normally have a lower variance than simply measuring post treatment, but the nature of the problem remains the same. How do I effectively take into account the variation induced by the group? If still not clear I will post another thread with an example of a situation like this, it may be clearer.

Comment: Have you considered a mixed effects model with groups are random effects? LMMs can handle complex (nested/crossed) structure in experimental data.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.